# When angular does generate the FormController?

Tags: angularjs, forms, controller

Quoting the angular documentation :

> FormController keeps track of all its controls and nested forms as well as the >  > state of them, such as being valid/invalid or dirty/pristine.
>
> Each form directive creates an instance of FormController.

When exactly is this FormController been generated ?

I have a form inside a directive, it seems that this form is generated after the link() function. This is a problem for me.

Comment: What is the problem you are running into specifically?

Comment: I've answered below when the controller is available. But you may be asking an XY question - that is, your issue may not be related to "when" FormController is generated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`form` directive has a controller - called colloquially FormController - which other directives could require - e.g. `ngModel` optionally requires `form`:

```
require: "?^form"
```

`form` directive can take the following forms:

```
<form>
```

or

```
<ANY ng-form>
```

Any time `form` directive (in any of its forms) is compiled and then linked, its FormController instance is available to those that `require` it.

The controller function of any directive (which constructs the controller instance) runs at **link-phase**, just before prelink.

Comment: Thank you very much for this explaination. So is it normal that in a directive (inside of which i have a <form>), the fields of the form is not in loaded when i want to access them in the link function of the directive ?

Comment: What do you mean by "fields of the form"? If you are referring to something like `$scope.form1.text1`, then it should be available - http://plnkr.co/edit/dXz6KvNzGSPKtiGKXCLT?p=preview / @julestruong